# MPI_Isend/Irecv only excuting in first iteration of for loop. What is preventing it from excecuting in subsequent iterations of the loop

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am  creating a program in which information from an array is being passed to different processors. In the code below i am trying to send information to and from processors repeatedly using a for loop. When i run the program on 5 and 2 cores, all the print statements are performed in the 1st iteration as expected but after this no more print statements are executed. The program doesn't exit with any error messages. It just hangs.Any thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /*MPI Specific Variables*/
  int my_size, my_rank, up, down;
  MPI_Request reqU, reqD, sreqU, sreqD;
  MPI_Status rUstatus, rDstatus, sUstatus, sDstatus;



  /*Other Variables*/
  int max_iter = 10;
  int grid_size = 1000;
  int slice;
  int x,y,j;


  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_size);

  /*Determining neighbours*/
  if (my_rank != 0) /*if statemets used to stop highest and lowest rank neighbours arent outside 0 - my_size-1 range of ranks*/
    {
      up = my_rank-1;
    }
  else
    {
      up = 0;
    }

  if(my_rank != my_size-1)
    {
      down = my_rank+1;
    }
  else
    {
      down = my_size-1;
    }

  /*cross-check: presumed my_size is a factor of gridsize else there are odd sized slices and this is not coded for*/
  if (grid_size%my_size != 0)
    {
      printf("ERROR - number of procs =  %d, this is not a factor of grid_size %d\n", my_size, grid_size);
      exit(0);
    }

  /*Set Up Distributed Data Approach*/
  slice = grid_size/my_size;
  printf("slice = %d\n", slice);




  double phi[slice+2][grid_size]; /*extra 2 rows to allow for halo data*/

  for (y=0; y < slice+2; y++)
    {
      for (x=0; x < grid_size; x++)
        {
          phi[y][x] = 0.0;
        }
    }



  for (j=0; j<max_iter +1; j++)
    {
      if (my_rank > 0)
        {
          printf("1. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
          /*send top most strip up one node to be recieved as bottom halo*/
          MPI_Isend(&phi[1][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, down, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &sreqU);
          printf("2. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
          /*recv top halo from up one node*/
          MPI_Irecv(&phi[slice + 1][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, down, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqU);
          printf("3. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
        }    

      if (my_rank < my_size -1)
        {
         printf("4. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
          /*recv top halo from down one node*/
         MPI_Irecv(&phi[0][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, up, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqD);
         printf("5. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
         /*send bottom most strip down one node to be recieved as top halo*/
         MPI_Isend(&phi[slice][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, up, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &sreqD);
         printf("6. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
        }


      if (my_rank>0)
        {
          printf("7. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
          /*Wait for send to down one rank to complete*/
          MPI_Wait(&sreqU, &sUstatus);
          printf("8. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
          /*Wait for recieve from up one rank to complete*/
          MPI_Wait(&reqU, &rUstatus);
          printf("9. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
        }

      if (my_rank < my_size-1)
        {
          printf("10. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
          /*Wait for send to up down one rank to complete*/
          MPI_Wait(&sreqD, &sDstatus);;
          printf("11. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
          /*Wait for recieve from down one rank to complete*/
          MPI_Wait(&reqD, &rDstatus);
          printf("12. myrank =%d\n",my_rank);
        }
  }

  printf("l\n");
  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with iterations, the remaining issue is with the computation of `up`/`down`. That is reversed in the code `up` is defined whenever `down` is needed... This didn't show in your previous code as `MPI_PROC_NULL` would just skip those communications.